# regex how to replace commas and ticks with new line and text

Tags: regex

i have this text:

```
'Airedale Terrier' , 'Akbash' , 'Akita' // and the list go on
```

i want it to be replaced with this for each breed:

```
this.breed.push({label: 'Airedale Terrier', value: 'Airedale Terrier'});
```

How can i do it using regex?

Comment: What language do you use? Different languages have different rules for regular expressions.

Comment: the language is typescript, i can run the regex on notepad++ though and copy it back to project.

Comment: Check this: https://regex101.com/r/pxVsZB/1

Comment: It is not clear from your example what has to be replaced with what. What happened to 'Akita' and 'Akbash' in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String:

```
'Airedale Terrier' , 'Akbash' , 'Akita'
```

Find(Regex):

```
('.*?')
```

Replace(Regex):

```
this.breed.push({label: $1 , value: $1 });\n
```

Try `\r\n` if `\n` doesn't works in the replace regex.

Output:

```
this.breed.push({label: 'Airedale Terrier' , value: 'Airedale Terrier' });
 , this.breed.push({label: 'Akbash' , value: 'Akbash' });
 , this.breed.push({label: 'Akita' , value: 'Akita' });
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pxVsZB/2

To rectify the output (Switch on multi-line and global flags):

Find: `^\s*,\s*(.*)` Replace `$1`

Demo https://regex101.com/r/by6DoE/2

Final Output:

```
this.breed.push({label: 'Airedale Terrier' , value: 'Airedale Terrier' });
this.breed.push({label: 'Akbash' , value: 'Akbash' });
this.breed.push({label: 'Akita' , value: 'Akita' });
```

Comment: can you fix it to return a new line for every breed?

Comment: @StathisNtonas Check now.

Comment: it didn't break lines, check whole list in breeds.txt in this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/G4Sm5zHwwAbbLPDhABmU?p=info

Comment: @StathisNtonas https://regex101.com/r/pxVsZB/3 and https://regex101.com/r/by6DoE/3